# Restful API without database connection

Tags: database, rest

My current project is a restful API that connects to a database to retrieve data.

1. What should be done if the route handlers can't access the database? In such a case I would implement a middleware that sends back a global response   that indicates that the API is temporarily not available.
2. Which status code should be returned? Internal Server Error (500) or Service Unavailable (503)?
3. Is it efficient if the middleware checks with each request the database connection?

Answer (score 0):

Well normal people dont understand 500 or 503 . so its better to catch these exceptions in catch block and then set some appropriate message .
Also for all your database related question explore database connection use connection pooling lib such as [HakariCp](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

Comment: It's a RESTful API, not a website: he should respond with a 503

Comment: same for the websites too

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But people using an API should understand a 503.

Comment: For the userfriendlyness I will send a json response that also includes a more understandable error message. HakariCP seemy nice but 'm programming in Go, not Java

Comment: try to find similar in go :-)